# Lighting in Box2D and Box2DLighting not working when used with a texture

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I'm having a problem with Textures and using lighting in a small prototype i'm working on. I understand how to implement the lighting using RayHandlers and whatnot, but when I then place a texture on top of a Body, the texture is always a constant visibility (E.g. not effected by light). At the moment I've just tried using a Spritebatch as you would normally render a texture to an object. Is there a different way to do this when using lighting?

Thanks, Lewis.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your textures to be affected by the lighting, you'll have to draw the textures first and then render the lights, like this:

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
        super.render(batch);

        Sprite sprite = (Sprite) body.getUserData();
        sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y);
        sprite.setOrigin(texture.getWidth()/2, texture.getHeight()/2);
        sprite.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
        sprite.draw(batch);

        rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(getCamera().combined);
        rayHandler.updateAndRender();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you show us the code . Without seeing your code I can just say that
 you must first draw the texture on the objects and the render the lights using rayhandler .